# Reclassify points in a LAS file using laspy

Tags: classification, las, point-cloud, laspy

I am trying to change the classification of all points in my las file above a certain height (z value) from 2 (ground) to 1 (unclassified). I wrote the following code to do this:

```
las = laspy.read("filtered plots/plot_37.las")
height_threshold = 333  # Replace with your desired Z value threshold

# Loop through the points, check their classification and height, and modify as needed
for point in las:
    if point.classification == 2 and point.z > height_threshold:
        point.classification = 1
        
las.write('plot_37.las')
```

However, upon reaching the line "point.classification = 1", I get the following error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

I do not understand why the code is trying to check length instead of simply reassigning the value of the classification field. How can I find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [numpy index syntax](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) to this, not a loop :

```
import laspy
las = laspy.read("filtered plots/plot_37.las") 
height_threshold = 333

# Classification set to "1" if the Z coord > height_threshold and classification = 2
las.classification[(las.z > height_threshold) & (las.classification == 2)] = 1

las.write('plot_37.las')
```